# Wakanda: trying to connect to an remote MySQL database

Tags: wakanda

I'm trying to connect to an remote MySQL database. When I created new mySql datastore model, Data classes were shown in designer (read-only). 
When i started the app following errors were displayed: 
[Wakanda Enterprise Server Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMxtT.png)

With Built-in DB everything was fine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use remote database, you need an enterprise version of wakanda and therefor a license as the first line of your error states.

> License not found. Server running in community mode.

You can get a license on [wakanda.io](http://wakanda.io).